# Blender not playing the right animations

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I made a simple block character to practice animating using armatures. I made four animations - idle, walking, running and jumping. It was working fine, I saved it and then closed it. The next day when I opened my blend file, and pressed Alt + A, it plays the Jumping animation. I thought maybe it was stuck on that animation last time, so I changed the animation, but now all the animations play the Jumping animation only.

I don't know what's wrong. Maybe it's something simple that I missed out or maybe I hit some shortcut key or feature by mistake and can't remember what I may have done. I've attached my .blend file. Please check it out and help me fix it, thank you.

[image]

Comment: Select any bone and change animation - everything is OK

Comment: Oh yeah, now it works. Thank you so much. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this was simple and silly. Just like [Serge L](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/29200/serge-l) said in the comments to the question. You need to click on one of the bones and then change the animation.

Pretty silly, but I think there might be others who might face the same problem when they start learning, so I am posting it here.

Thank You Serge.